# How to create a complexe header with multi row + nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started with bootstrap and despite official documentation I'm stuck for a complex case .
Here's what I want to do :

[image]

I know how to make lines, navbar, show and hide them but I wonder how to make the header version of the site and switch to a single line.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I'd be curious to see this come together. You are not likely to get -- good -- help unless you provide the html in a fiddle, jsbin, codepen, or bootply. Make an effort and create the largest version. To get you started the larger viewport version is three columns, probably a col-md-3, col-md-6, and .col-md-3, you would use the grid structure in the docs then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS @media [Sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Just to simplify everything

```
<style>
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    }
 }
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    }

 }
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
    table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    }

 }
</style>
```